# Preventing second function from being called in same ng-click in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an ng-click with 2 functions in it.

1. Function1: A function in a directive that sets a scope variable to
   true/false
2. Function2: A function in the controller

Right now in Function2 in the beginning I check the value of the scope variable from Function1 and if it's false I return false(i.e. stop it).

So my question is: can the Function2 not be called in case the first one returns false without writing anything in the Function2?

Thank you.

Comment: Pass the variable to the controller function.
`ng-click="directiveFunction(); controllerFunction(booleanVariable);"`

Comment: @marneborn I do something similar now, that's what I want to get rid of. My question is if the call of Function2 can be stopped in Function1(directive) without tohuvhing the directive.
@ HarishR I don't imagine how to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ng-click="directiveFunction(); booleanVariable ? controllerFunction() : noop();"
```

From here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression

> **No Control Flow Statements**
>
> Apart from the ternary operator (a ? b : c), you cannot write a control flow statement in an
>   expression. The reason behind this is core to the Angular philosophy that application logic
>   should be in controllers, not the views. If you need a real conditional, loop, or to throw
>   from a view expression, delegate to a JavaScript method instead.